# making rate table in relative survival

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

The package "survexp.fr" can calculate relative survival. Input are your data (in my case patients diagnosed with breast cancer) and then the rate table which includes the change of surviving to the next age category, generally split by sex and year of diagnosis.

In my case, I want to have relative survival according to age, sex, year of diagnosis. I have all the data that should go into the rate table in 1 data frame:

```
id  age sex survival    hazard  year
1   18  1   0.96394 0.00154 1960
2   19  1   0.96246 0.00164 1961
3   20  1   0.96088 0.00176 1962
4   21  1   0.95919 0.00188 1963
5   22  1   0.95739 0.00190 1964
6   23  1   0.95557 0.00185 1965
```

I am looking for a quick and easy way to transform this into the 'ratetable' similar the rate table for French or USA. I searched a lot but found nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: "data frame" is not a term typically used in SQL.  You should remove the SQL tags and add the tags that are appropriate for the tool you are using.